# Entity Framework ASP NET obtener el id de un insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Hola quisiera obtener el id de un query que estoy haciendo para que con ese mismo pueda hacer otro query de insert en otra tabla usando **Entity  Framework**

```js
using(DBEnt db = new DBEnt()) {

  var credit = new Creditos() {
    img = img,
      title = data.title,
      descripcion = data.descripcion
  };

  db.Creditos.Add(credit);
db.SaveChanges();
  var idNew = alguna forma de obtener el id de db.Creditos.Add(credit);

  var otraTabla = new oTable() {
    id = idNew,
      otrodato = 'otros datos'
  }
  db.oTable.add(otraTabla);
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: La key de la tabla la defines como IDENTITY o sea autonumerica ? o sea es una key que genera la db al insertar. Esto debes indicarlo en el mapping, si lo haces al insertar el valor se asigna directo a la instancia de la entidad que estas persistiendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using(DBEnt db = new DBEnt()) {

  var credit = new Creditos() {
    img = img,
      title = data.title,
      descripcion = data.descripcion
  };

  db.Creditos.Add(credit);
db.SaveChanges();
  var idNew = credit.Id; //Y si no le hace, utiliza: credit.id

  var otraTabla = new oTable() {
    id = idNew,
      otrodato = 'otros datos'
  }
  db.oTable.add(otraTabla);
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Material recomendado: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes una navegacion entre esas dos tablas no necesitas realiza un insert primero para luego aplicar el id generado en el siguiente, se puede realizar en una misma operacion si las tablas estan mapeadas en su relacion

```
using(DBEnt db = new DBEnt()) {

  var credit = new Creditos() {
      img = img,
      title = data.title,
      descripcion = data.descripcion
  };

  db.Creditos.Add(credit);


  var otraTabla = new oTable() {
    cretit = credit,
    otrodato = 'otros datos'
  }

  db.oTable.add(otraTabla);

  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

como veras en la propiedad de navegacion `cretit` en `oTable` asignas la instancia, esto hara que al aplicar el `SaveChanges()` entity framework inserte en secuencia y las relaciones automaticamente

Pero remarco que no asignas el id de la primer tabla sino su instancia en la propiedad que permite relacionarlas

[Guardado de datos relacionados](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/saving/related-data)